# Limit date range based on first selected date

Tags: javascript, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using `bootstrap-datepicker`. I have 2 input field and I want to restrict second input for only the next 5 days from the first date after user select date from first input field.

```
date 1 <input type="text" class="datepicker"><br>
date 2 <input type="text" class="datepicker2"><br>

$(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
        autoclose: true
        }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
            var startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());

            $('.datepicker2').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);

            $('.datepicker2').datepicker('endDate', '+5d')
        });
});

$(function(){
    $('.datepicker2').datepicker({
        format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
        autoclose: true,
        //endDate: '+5d'
    });
});
```

This is currently not working. It does worked though if I put it in `datepicker2` attribute. Please help and thanks in advance

Here's the code example : http://jsfiddle.net/jnh8pyst/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you must use [`setEndDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#setenddate) method and create the `endDate` plus x days you want, taking as a base the `startDate` and then use the `setEndDate` for the desired picker.

```
let endDate = new Date(startDate);
endDate = new Date(endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 5));
$('.datepicker2').datepicker('setEndDate', endDate);
```

To the end you will have:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
    autoclose: true
  }).on('changeDate', function(selected) {
    let startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    let endDate = new Date(startDate);
    endDate = new Date(endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 5));
    $('.datepicker2').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
    $('.datepicker2').datepicker('setEndDate', endDate);
  });

  $('.datepicker2').datepicker({
    format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
    autoclose: true,
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.2.0/css/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.2.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
Date 1
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
<br> Date 2
<input type="text" class="datepicker2">
<br>
```